# Polymorphism in RESTFul server

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I have 3 classes. A is abstract class, B and C extends A.
I want to be able to get a JSON in a POST (A) and then to decide what type it is and to convert to the correct type. in other words to use only one end point for both B and C. The same I want to do in GET, I want to get a one list that contains B and C objects. 
Does it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, what you want is to be able to handle polymorphic types.
There are many frameworks that could help you, I personally use jackson 2, you can check here for an example:

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations#handling-polymorphic-types

Answer (score 0):

A, B and C usually have names, like Animal, Dog and Cat.
Therefore those are different resources like `/animal`, `/animal/dog` and `/animal/cat`. Following this rule, you can determine the type by the requestUrl. A `http-post` for `/animal/dog` should result in a `dog` resource and a `/animal/cat` in a `cat`. Both `http-post` could use the same JSON of course.

For `http-get`, the requested resouce might be `/animals` containing a combined list of the resources `/animal/cats` (list of all `/animal/cat`) and `/animal/dogs` (a list of all `/animal/dog`)

If you go down the path your are mentioning in your question, you can just dump everything to `/stuff` like cats, dogs, tricycles, contracts, space ships ... Not very restful.